# Check if there are a looping reference in a variable?

Tags: php

Is there a way to detect if a PHP array contains a self-reference? Example: the variable `$GLOBALS` has a self-reference. If I do a looping array with nested calls, PHP breaks. For instance:

```
function nested_call ($data) {
  foreach ($data as $value) {
    if (is_array($value)) { 
      nested_call($value);
    }
  }
}
```

The above example will work with:

```
array(1,2,3,array(4,5,6,array(7,8,9)))
```

But will fail with `$GLOBALS` because it self-reference. Is there some way to check, before start `nested_call` again?

Comment: It would be very hard. Why don't add `depth`?

Comment: If I define a *depth* it'll be recursive *n* times until the depth value, without hidden that.